Trouble with npm Install: Seeking Guidance on Version Compatibility (Angular V16)
I've been encountering some frustrating issues with npm installation lately, and I could really use some assistance. Every time I try to run npm install, I seem to stumble upon incompatible version errors that bring my development workflow to a grinding halt. It's becoming increasingly frustrating, and I'm sure I'm not alone in facing this challenge.
i want to migrate my angular version to 16
here's is my package.json
{
  "name": "HighS",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.16.0",
    "npm": "^8.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.6",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.2.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^16.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.2.0",
  }
}

Thank you in advance
i want to migrate my angular version to 16  and Every time I try to run npm install, I seem to stumble upon incompatible version errors

Post the error and your node version. Not sure if it's all versions of angular but I think it tells you what version you need in the error.

Many errors are present. Is there anyone who has a compatible version that resolves all of them? I don't have any issues with the Angular version; the most important thing for me is to upgrade them to Angular 16.

Many errors are better than zero for debugging the issue. I do believe there is a list on the angular site that goes over compatibility.

Upgrading to the latest packages would help

Install the tool npm install -g npm-check-updates
Verify that your package.json is checked into version control (the
next command will overwrite the package.json)
Update the package.json ncu --upgrade
Validate the changes to your package.json
Install the new packages npm install


i want only to upgrade to version 16 not to the lastest version

give this a try > npm uninstall -g angular-cli > npm cache clean > npm install -g angular-cli@[your version]  and check your node version. sometimes moving back to old node version works
